# SQL Error : Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert Id with the help of output clause but I get this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_Master_DimensionValues
(
    Id int, 
    [Name] varchar(max), 
    [FullName] varchar(max), 
    ID_DimensionHierarchyType varchar(max),
    StartDate varchar(max), 
    EndDate varchar(max)
)
```

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE ([ID] INT); 

INSERT INTO #TEMP_Master_DimensionValues 
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID] INTO @OutputTbl([ID])
    SELECT 
        'April01-17' [Name], 
        '''Week of ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (SELECT Min('2021-04-01') FROM Master_DimensionValues), 107) [FullName],
        '3' [ID_DimensionHierarchyType], 
        '2021-04-01' [StartDate], 
        NULL [EndDate];
```

The select statement above is correct and returns a result, but I couldn't figure out what's going wrong when I am trying into `#TEMP_Master_DimensionValues`. If anybody could help me it would be appreciated

Comment: Simple math shows 6 columns defined in your temp table but only 5 columns in your select (may have been more obvious if (a) you put `Name` on its own line, and (b) used a column list in your `INSERT`). If you want `Id` to be an `IDENTITY` column then it should be defined as such (and you still will need to specify the column list in your `INSERT`).

Comment: As the error message states, you are not providing values for all the columns: Where is `ID` in your columns? Try specying the columns you are actually inserting.

Comment: OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID] INTO @OutputTbl([ID]) that is supposed to add the Id values I suppose

Comment: Just naming a column `ID` does not make it magically generate values for you.

Comment: That would work *if* ID was an *Identity* column - which in your example it is not.

Comment: As best practice you should always list the columns you are inserting into... then this error won't happen.

Comment: More on why you should never just say `INSERT {tbl} SELECT ...` and should always say `INSERT {tbl}({col1},{col2}) SELECT ...`: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list#insert)

Comment: `StartDate varchar(max),` Nope - this column (and EndDate) should be defined as Date. Develop good habits - choose your datatypes carefully. Storing dates as strings will only increase the risk that you allow invalid values into your table, creating more work for others. In addition, `varchar(max)` should not be your default datatype for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **always** recommend to be **explicit** about the columns you are inserting into - so change your `INSERT` statement to be like this:

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE ([ID] INT); 

INSERT INTO #TEMP_Master_DimensionValues ([Name], [FullName], ID_DimensionHierarchyType, StartDate, EndDate)
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID] INTO @OutputTbl([ID])
    SELECT 
        'April01-17' [Name], 
        '''Week of ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (SELECT Min('2021-04-01') FROM Master_DimensionValues), 107) [FullName],
        '3' [ID_DimensionHierarchyType], 
        '2021-04-01' [StartDate], 
        NULL [EndDate];
```

Also, I'd **highly recommend** not just making everything a `varchar(max)` - use the **most appropriate** datatype - always - so a `StartDate` or `EndDate` should really be `DATE` (or alternatively `DATETIME2(n)`) - but **most certainly NOT** `varchar(max)`!